# Why is the return value of useEffect not getting called when my component unmounts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen when navigating to the next screen "unmount" i want to reset the state to be the initial values, but for some reason, it's not triggered anymore

I use a separate `useEffect` just for cleanup, but I did not figure the issue!

code snippet

```
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<Service | undefined>(
    undefined,
  );
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isClose, setIsClose] = useState<boolean>(false);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    getServices();
    let format = 'hh:mm:ss A';
    let timeNow = moment(time, format),
      startTime = moment('04:00:00 pm', format),
      EndTime = moment('11:00:00 pm', format);
    if (!timeNow.isBetween(startTime, EndTime)) {
      isOpen && Alert.alert('Please, Select Time between 04pm - 11pm');
      isOpen && setIsReady(false);
    } else {
      isOpen && setIsReady(true);
    }
  }, [time, getServices, isOpen]);

/**
      React.useEffect(
        () => () => {
          setIsOpen(false);
          setIsClose(false);
          setSelectedItem(undefined);
          setSelectedIndex(null);
          console.log('cleared'); // not logging
        },
        [],
      );
*/

// navigate to next screen 
const sendData = () => {
setIsClose(true);
setTimeout(() => {
  // setIsUnMount((prev) => !prev);
 // setIsOpen(false);
  setIsClose(false);
  setSelectedItem(undefined);
  setSelectedIndex(null);
  navigation.navigate('MapScreen', {
    serviceInfo: selectedItem,
    timeReport: moment(time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('hh:mm A'),
    dateReport: moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
   });
  }, 100);
};



<BottomModal
        onDismissFC={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        openModal={isOpen}
        closeModal={isClose}
        points={[height * 0.66]}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: Colors.background}}>
          .....

        </View>
      </BottomModal>
```

Modal component

```
import React, {useCallback, useMemo, useRef} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {
  BottomSheetBackdrop,
  BottomSheetModal,
  BottomSheetModalProvider,
} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import {Colors} from '../styles';

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  openModal?: boolean;
  closeModal?: boolean;
  points: number[] | string[];
  onDismissFC?: () => void;
}

const BottomModal = ({
  children,
  onDismissFC,
  points,
  openModal,
  closeModal,
}: Props) => {
  const bottomSheetModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => points, [points]);
  const handlePresentModalPress = useCallback(() => {
    bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
  }, []);

  const handleDismissPress = useCallback(() => {
    bottomSheetModalRef.current?.dismiss();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    openModal && handlePresentModalPress();
    closeModal && handleDismissPress();
  }, [openModal, closeModal, handlePresentModalPress, handleDismissPress]);
  return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <BottomSheetModal
        backgroundComponent={() => <View style={styles.modalHandleStyle} />}
        ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
        backdropComponent={BottomSheetBackdrop}
        // animationDuration={250}
        onDismiss={onDismissFC}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}>
        <View style={styles.contentModalContainer}>{children}</View>
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  );
};

export default BottomModal;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalHandleStyle: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: Colors.background,
  },
  contentModalContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.background,
  },
});
```

Comment: If the component unmounts then what is the point of setting any state? This doesn't make any sense. What is the issue you are trying to solve for? My guess is that `react-navigation` isn't *actually* unmounting components when you navigate around your app. Perhaps you need to clear any state in the timeout callback before you issue navigation.

Comment: I have a modal i open it when choosing an item, and when I navigate to the next screen I return the open state to the initial value, so when the user want to back from the second screen to the first screen and what to choose another item the modal not opened for some reason, so I thought to just return the open state to initial value in unmounting

Comment: @DrewReese I Edit the Q and added the modal component can you check it please?

Comment: I don't think the modal is the issue. I see you do actually reset some state in that `sendData` callback. Is that *actually* being called from somewhere?

Comment: @DrewReese yes i invoke it when i press to Continue button to navigate to the next screen, I think the issue with the modal itself, I just add the bottom sheet directly in this screen and when to choose an item I call `bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();` but just work at first time screen mounted otherways "go back from the second screen to first one" not work anymore

Comment: I'm not as familiar with RN as I am React, but if you could try creating an [Expo Snack](https://expo.io/) I can take a look at it while it's running.

Comment: @OliverD Going out on a limb here, but it's probably because your screen isn't actually unmounting, it's just being hidden. Depending on how you have your navigation configured, screens are often mounted "lazily" and then remain mounted after they've been visited the first time.

Comment: @Adam yep, I'm sure I return all state to initial values when Unmounted, and when I select any item from the list I can see it in logs, that's mean the function invoked well but the modal not opening

Comment: @DrewReese here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/bottom-modal---unmounted-issue) in iOS simulator that works well, Android not, and in my project, the issue still (modal not open) I hope you understand my point well 

Comment: In that second Snack, I dropped a `React.useEffect(() => () => console.log('HomeScreen unmounted'), []);` in your `HomeScreen` and after pressing "next", either on the main screen or in the BottomSheetModal, the component never unmounts. When I set an effect to log state updates, I see it correctly resets when doing the navigation.

Comment: @DrewReese hmm, so what's the issue here?

Comment: I don't know, you tell us. You say the issue is an effect cleanup function isn't running when unmounting, I was confirming my suspicion that the navigation/routing package you use doesn't *actually* unmount components when you navigate, and secondly confirming that state is is updating when you navigate. I was only able to run your Snack on iOS though, it fails to load Android and Web.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, you are right I was reading this now https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/ I will come back as soon as possible with the answer and solve the problem, Thanks for your time :))

Answer (score 0):

React performs the cleanup when the component `unmounts`. `effects` run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up 'effects' from the previous render before running the effects next time.

In general case, your state will be reset to initial state if you come from another `screen`.

***In your case, `Modal/Dialog` is not considered as different `screen (route)`. If you would like to reset to initial state then you need to use your own function which will do that job as callback function (let's say onClose Modal/Dialog).***